# ARC Async Block Best Practices

Tags: ios, http, automatic-ref-counting, nsurlrequest

My application sends lots of messages via `HTTP` requests. I wrote a simple wrapper around an HTTP request that has a primary method to fire off a request and return any `NSData` as result.

It looks like this:

```
- (void)sendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                         NSURLResponse *response,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         NSLog(@"---->> request returned");

                                         if (_delegate == nil)
                                             return;

                                         if (error == nil) {
                                             // forward along
                                             [_delegate requestReturnedResult:data withResponse:response];

                                         }
                                         else {
                                             // error occurred
                                             [_delegate requestReturnedError:error withResponse:response];
                                         }
                                     }] resume];
}
```

This `HttpRequestHelper` object is a `ivar` of a my message abstraction object `OutboundMessage` that packages up data and then sends it out.

I think have a `MessageSender` object that takes some data, creates a `OutboundMessage` object, and sends it out.

This abstraction works nicely except I think I'm bumping into an issue with ARC.

When someone calls `[MessageSender send:]`, I `alloc` an `OutboundMessage` and send it out.

What I see via `NSLog` is that my `OutboundMessage` is cleaned up (presumably when `send` exits, then I see the `HttpRequestHelper` cleaned up. **Then** I see the `NSLog` in the completion handler of my `dataTaskWithRequest`.

This indicates to me that everything around my request helper was cleaned up prior to the HTTP request completing. Then as you can imagine, soon I try to bubble up my response via the `delegate`, I get `exc_bad_access`.

I can think of some creative ways to prevent the deallocation and prevent this but what I'd like to know is conceptually what are best practices for handling this pattern of firing off messages where the enveloping objects clean up only after the request is done.

Thanks.

**Update**
Each wrapper object was using the `initWithDelegate:self` style patterns and I noticed those delegates were being saved like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<HttpRequesterDelegate> delegate;
```

I changed to them to `strong` and it seems to correct it but I'm not sure if I'm leaking memory now or if there's a more optimal approach.

Comment: Changing it to strong will likely cause you to leak memory unless you are setting the delegate to nil somewhere after the call comes back.

Comment: Hmm, since Im doing `initWithDelegate:self` would it suffice to set the delegate to nil in each `dealloc`? What are alternative solutions to this problem?

Comment: `OutboundMessage` is `NSdata` object? How do you create `request` object from `OutboundMessage`?

Comment: `OutboundMessage` just holds some text (json) that ends up sent as part of the HTTP request. So someone calls `send` which takes the payload and builds an `OutboundMessage message` and calls `[message send]` which then calls the `HttpRequestHelper sendRequest` method above (after building an `NSURLRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `NSURLSessionDataTask` object, that was created by `NSURLSession - dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:` method, retains `completionHandler` block object. The block object isn't released until the block is executed when the data task finished.

Next, Blocks capture(retain) local variables automatically. The following line in the code

```
if (_delegate == nil)
```

is the same as

```
if (self.delegate == nil)
```

If `delegate` property is `strong`

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<HttpRequesterDelegate> delegate;
```

Then `self` is retained by the block. In this case, `self` is `HttpRequestHelper` object. So `HttpRequestHelper` object and `delegate` object live as long as the data task finished. It's safe.

But `delegate` property is `assign`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<HttpRequesterDelegate> delegate;
```

It is the same as `__unsafe_unretained`. Blocks doesn't retain `__unsafe_unretained` object at all. Thus `self` wasn't retained, it would be released before the data task finished.

**ADDED**

In this case, you can use a local variable to retain `delegate` object. Because the completionHandler uses only the `delegate` object, not `HttpRequestHelper` object itself.

```
id<HttpRequesterDelegate> delegate = _delegate;

[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                                     NSURLResponse *response,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"---->> request returned");

                                     /*
                                      * Use `delegate` instead of `_delegate`
                                      */
                                     if (delegate == nil)
                                         return;

                                     ...
```

In this case, the attribute of `delegate` property is strong or assign, it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Are you saying in this case my `delegate` should be strong?

Comment: Yes, it should be strong.

Comment: I thought the typical delegate pattern was to use assign?